# C# vs. Delphi speed for External Sorting

Tags: c#, delphi

I have a 500+GB text file. it has to be searched for duplicates, remove them, sort and save final file. Of course for such big file, the LINQ or such things are not good at all and will not work so they have to use External Sorting. there is an app called "Send-Safe List Manager". its speed is super fast, for a 200MB txt file it gives the result in less than 10  seconds. after examining inside the exe using "Greatis WinDowse" app i found that it has been written in Delphi. there are some external sorting classes written in C#. i have tested a 200MB file with them and all were over 1 minute. so my question is that for this kind of calculations is Delphi faster than C# and if i have to write my own, then should i use delphi? and with C# can i reach that speed at all?

Comment: It might not be a C# vs Delphi issue as much as it is an algorithm performance issue.

Comment: Basically, this has nothing to do with the programming language.

Comment: sort -u $HUGE_FILE > sorted_huge_file.txt

Comment: I think delphi or c# will not be the better for you. because none of those languages where designed for that, you should use something like awk to do this and you will got incredible performance and is VERY easy to do this.

Comment: http://webandlife.blogspot.com/2011/12/c-performance-vs-delphi-performance.html   this article says delphi is 3 times fast against c# for some calculations

Comment: @Hossein That website is simply wrong. It’s comparing apples with oranges – like almost all benchmarks on that subject.

Comment: Thanks, so i have been doing all wrong. thanks for guiding.

Comment: Now, if you want code to help you big sorts/remove duplicates (in that order of course) in Delphi, that is an entire new question that we could help you with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properly written sorting code for large file *must be disk bound* - at that point there essentially no difference what language you use.

Answer (score 6):

Delphi generates native code and also allows for inline assembly, so in theory, maximum speed for a specific algorithm could be easier to reach in Delphi.

However, the performance of what you describe will be tied to the IO performance, and the performance difference between possible algorithms will be of several orders of magnitude more than the Delphi vs. .NET difference.

The language is probably the last thing you should look at if trying to speed that up.